# Julia Array Range Access

Tags: julia

Creating an Array like `d = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` creates a `1x9` array of dimension 2 (side question: Why two dimensions?).

This can be used as a row vector in matrix and vector multiplication.
Accessing a range of `d[2:5]` does not return the values arranged in a `1x4` array. The result is basically a column vector with dimensions `4x1`.
(In Matlab/Octave the dimensions are maintained when accessing the range of a vector.)

However, a row vector is returned with `d[:,2:5]` (but not with `d[1,2:5]`).

This seems odd to me, because this means I always have to be aware of row/column vectors.
So is this really the intended use or am I on the wrong path?
Also, can someone explain why `d[:,2:5]` works but `d[1,2:5]` does not?

Comment: "I always have to be aware of row/column vectors" I think this is the intended behaviour.

`d = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` has two dimensions as everything that expands on multiple "columns" has the second dimension, even if the row is just one.

Comment: Just FYI asking multiple questions in a single SO post is generally not advised.

Comment: Technically speaking, the  "row vector" you mentioned above is actually a `1 -row Matrix` aka `1x4 Array`. In Julia, we do have a `RowVector` type(e.g. `d[2:5].'` and we [take vector transposes seriously](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4774): `[1,2,3].' * [1,2,3] #=> 14` but `[1 2 3] * [1,2,3] #=> [14] (1-element array)`. Unlike those "sloppy" languages, you have to be seriously aware of all of these in Julia ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Copying in @Gnimuc's comment because I think it's important.

> Technically speaking, the "row vector" you mentioned above is actually
>   a `1 -row Matrix` aka `1x4 Array`. In Julia, we do have a `RowVector`
>   type(e.g. `d[2:5].'` and we take vector transposes seriously:
>   `[1,2,3].' * [1,2,3] #=> 14` but `[1 2 3] * [1,2,3] #=> [14]
>   (1-element array).` Unlike those "sloppy" languages, you have to be
>   seriously aware of all of these in Julia ;)

---

```
d = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

> creates a 1x9 array of dimension 2 (side question: Why two dimensions?).

because that's the syntax to create a to create a two dimensional array? use `d = [1, 2, 3]` or `d = [1; 2; 3]` to create a 1-D array (or a column Vector).

---

> row vector is returned with d[:,2:5] (but not with d[1,2:5]).
>
> This seems odd to me, because this means I always have to be aware of
>   row/column vectors. So is this really the intended use or am I on the
>   wrong path? Also, can someone explain why d[:,2:5] works but d[1,2:5]
>   does not?

Indexing with an Integer leads to dropping of the dimension whereas indexing with a Range (or any AbstractVector) will not drop it. There was a lot of discussion about this decision when it was made which I won't repeat here but have a look [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5949) amongst other places.

In terms of "I always have to be aware of row/column vectors", that's because whether you have a row or column vector means something different, so naturally one should be aware of it. For example, if there was no difference then the distinguishing between following would be impossible:

```
julia> [1, 2, 3] .* [ 1 2 3 ]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 2  4  6
 3  6  9

julia> [1, 2, 3] .* [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 9
```

Hope that's helpful in some way...

Comment: Thank you and the comments above. This (and the linked discussion) does help me. I was apparently expecting too much octave/matlab behavior :)